# Searchable grails plugin ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer$TokenStreamComponents

Tags: grails, lucene, compass, searchable

i'm using the searchable 0.6.9 plugin with grails 2.4.4 and on my development machine (Windows/IntelliJ IDEA) everything works fine. Deploying it on my Tomcat on linux, however, gives me the following error:

```
    ...

    2014-12-01 10:20:46,066 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grails.plugin.searchable.SearchableController': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'searchableService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'compass': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer$TokenStreamComponents
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'searchableService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'compass': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer$TokenStreamComponents
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'compass': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer$TokenStreamComponents
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer$TokenStreamComponents
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.analyzer.CoreAnalyzerBuilderDelegate.buildAnalyzer(CoreAnalyzerBuilderDelegate.java:47)
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.analyzer.DefaultLuceneAnalyzerFactory.createAnalyzer(DefaultLuceneAnalyzerFactory.java:81)
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.analyzer.LuceneAnalyzerManager.buildAnalyzer(LuceneAnalyzerManager.java:225)
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.analyzer.LuceneAnalyzerManager.buildAnalyzers(LuceneAnalyzerManager.java:133)
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.analyzer.LuceneAnalyzerManager.<init>(LuceneAnalyzerManager.java:67)
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.LuceneSearchEngineFactory.<init>(LuceneSearchEngineFactory.java:119)
    at org.compass.core.impl.DefaultCompass.<init>(DefaultCompass.java:124)
    at org.compass.core.impl.DefaultCompass.<init>(DefaultCompass.java:117)
    at org.compass.core.config.CompassConfiguration.buildCompass(CompassConfiguration.java:288)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.spring.SearchableCompassFactoryBean.buildCompass(SearchableCompassFactoryBean.java:95)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.spring.SearchableCompassFactoryBean.getObject(SearchableCompassFactoryBean.java:58)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.spring.SearchableCompassFactoryBean.getObject(SearchableCompassFactoryBean.java:41)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer$TokenStreamComponents
    ... 17 more
```

It seems as if the org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer class does not contain TokenStreamComponents in lucene 2.4.1 (which is a dependency of searchable 0.6.9). But as I wrote, it works fine on my development machine.

PS: On Linux the war file is built by hudson.

**UPDATE:**

On my dev machine it does not run as war either but run-app does. I have no clue why it tries to use a method that is not present when running as a war file.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

Unfortunately the solution was simple: I had the Jasper plugin installed as well and it loads lucene 4.5.1 as dependency.
By excluding it with

```
compile (":jasper:1.10.0") {
            excludes 'org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:4.5.1'
            excludes 'org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:4.5.1'
            excludes 'org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:4.5.1'
        }
```

everything works as expected.